# General types of output of a computer

Tags: terminology

I am trying to understand what are the general types of output of a computer.
I assume the following described general types of output are the only ones in the cosmos, but I might be wrong:

- **Screened Raw Data:** Output such as a document available only to be read but not edited (as when opened with a reading-only "viewer" program)
- **Screened Interface:** Output such as a document available to be both read and edited (as when opened with a text editor)
- **Spatial Change:** Output such as the result of a computerized machine, or alternatively, a computer embedded system (such as a robot and maybe also quantum computer or some physical yet non material computer of some sort)

<sub>A similar try is defining what are the only possible ways to input data into computer, such as with CLUI, TUI, GUI and possibly other methods.</sub>

Is there a consensus among computer scientists and/or UX researchers about what are the general types of output of a computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not interested in pointing out any standardization document, but an output depending on user's activity doesn't have to be observed immediately like it is happening with personalization, recommendation or some other purposes.

Since the inputs may vary and the aim of your question is about outputs here, I can tell the recommendation tools use user's input and send them to the let's say DB to make further computations. Anyway user may not be affected with the result of the input as he/she can see or outputs may not be visible all the time at least.