# When to show a toast message in Settings page

Tags: toast

In a Settings page, what would be an acceptable practice when it comes to showing toast messages to the user to notify about changes applied?

1. On exiting after change of settings in a particular section
2. On exiting the entire settings page after changes

Comment: What's a toast message?

Answer (score 3):

As I stated with [**one of my previous answer**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/115970/why-opt-for-right-sided-nav-drawers/115978#115978) and it's thought like a default case for [**questions**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130346/general-types-of-output-of-a-computer/130348), users are mentally expect their action's result immediately or in a limited time frame relatively. To change this might lead your customers to expect the same thing with the rest of your product too.

> I'd show these notifications whenever it's possible after
>   these settings saved. It means;

- If you have a separate **`SAVE`** button for this, then after the button
  clicked and the settings saved to the all sources,
- If the settings are saved right after it's changed via any kind of inputs (button, slider, etc.), then you might wanna put an **`OK`** like button at the end to make sure your users, the settings are saved (to the all sources if any server exists) and then you may send them a toast message right after exiting *(Imagine showing a notification each time whenever user drops the slider bar)*.

**Briefly, notifying users whenever the settings are saved, even one-by-one or all in one is far best experience I have ever ran into.**